# Why td border-radius is applied to content but not the border

Tags: html, css

I try to apply a border-radius to the table data (td) element and have a border around it. But only the inner content has the rounded corners, the border stays a rectangle. Here is a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/pm9qhkt3/

Stangely enough the same exact code does *WORK* insided stackoverflow inline tool, see below:

```css
.border {
  padding: 10px;
  border-color: red;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="border">
    Caption1
  </td>
  <td class="border">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="border">
    Caption2
  </td>
  <td class="border">
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JSFiddle:
[image]

StackOverflow:
[image]

Comment: I found a difference in css - StackOverflow has `border-collapse: separate` wich does the trick, but it does not look to the the "proper"solution

Comment: I can't see how the property is enabled in the fiddle. If I copy only its content over to a new fiddle, it works the same as the snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not allowing the borders to be separate from one another.

You have `border-collapse: collapse` as part of the CSS you're getting via JSFiddle.  What that tells the browser is that *these borders HAVE to touch*.  You don't want that, obviously.

So, if you add this to your CSS, it'll solve it:

```
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
}
```

You'll probably want to target that with a bit more specificity than I provided there, but that's the general idea.  If you're rounding borders on table cells, allow them to separate from one another.

## [Link to JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pm9qhkt3/1/)

Of course, different browsers and interpreters will have different style rules for their tables (just like they do for `p` `blockquote` and other elements).  So in some instances it'll work out of the box when the default `border-collapse` property is `separate`.  I have no clue if modern IE still has that as its default, but I know that IE 6-8 did, just as an example.

Comment: No, this is not the default. `separate` is the default value.

Comment: Haha, it's not always the default, and I added on to my answer just as you posted that.  Check it out in Chrome, for instance.  `border-collapse: collapse` is indeed the default.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are saying that, because a simple test reveals that it's not true. You are still working with the fiddle that had the normalise stylesheet enabled, right?

Comment: Well, I'm not going to argue with you about it, but it seemed to help the asker.  I hope you have a wonderful evening!

Comment: Look at the fiddle source. It links to <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">. That is where the styles come in. If you were to make a simple HTML file, without any reset stylesheets, you would see that the property is `separate` instead.

Answer (score 3):

In jsfiddle they have used normalize.css where the table has the property

```
table{
border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

uncheck that in inspect element and see.. it works same like inline stackoverflow tool.

Answer (score 0):

Try to this.

```css
.border {
  padding: 10px;
  border-color: red;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: silver;
}
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="border">
    Caption1
  </td>
  <td class="border">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="border">
    Caption2
  </td>
  <td class="border">
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.border {
  padding: 10px;
  border-color: red;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: silver;
}

table {
  border-collapse: inherit
}
```

Try this, it's works

Answer (score 0):

```
table {width: 100%;
   border-collapse: separate !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc;
}
```